Set Conditional Color formatting Slicer on Measure Value
I have two Slicers with Years. Trying to set Background of one of them  depending on Value in another. Set Background-> Conditional Formatting -> Field Value -> WrongYearSelected
where:
WrongYearSelected = IF((SELECTEDVALUE('dim_date'[Year]) <= 'ComparisonYear'[YearSelected]), "Yellow")

What I'm doing wrong?
tried to use Measure, Calculated Field for thatr

For best results, I recommend putting a shape behind your slicer and setting the shape color to your measure. Then make the background of your slicer transparent. This measure I got working by using a shape:
WrongYearSelected = 
VAR dimDate = MIN('dim_date'[Year])
VAR compYear = MIN('ComparisonYear'[YearSelected])

RETURN
IF( dimDate <= compYear, "Yellow","White")


As a side note, I recommend this method because (in my research) changing the background of the slicer was hit or miss. That measure would only work when applied to the ComparisonYear slicer and the dimDate slicer was changed.

tried your example - works, but only when I changing 'dim_date' Slicer.
just wondering why you used MIN ?
purpose of whole task is to compare selected values of both slicer

I got the same result when setting the measure as the slicer background. Which is why I recommend using a shape instead.
MIN  works the similar to SelectedValue in a slicer, however this article suggests that multiple values may be pulled back. So MIN works better to get a single value.
